# A good strategy for Jade template inheritance with external modules, on Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, express, pug

I'm working on a Framework where developers can implement a child template in an external module. I would like to include later that template in a parent template.

Here  is a basic template schema :

> ─ mission (parent  template)
>           ├─ succeed mission (child template)
>           ├─ failed mission (child template)
>           └─ play mission (child template)

The parent template is the same for everyone. The children templates are implemented by a contributor and always displayed in a different moment (mission state).

I try two approaches in a single template file.

Implement a "block" pattern :

```
block mission_play
  h2 Hello world!
  p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
block mission_succeed
  h2 Congratulations!
  p You won buddy!
block mission_failed
  h2 Oh my gosh, dude, you did something realy bad
  p You should try again
```

That one won't work because I haven't got any `extend layout` directive (that I can't use because every child template is an external module). **Is there any way to indicate manually to jade which template extend ?**

Implement every child template in a mixin:

```
mixin mission_introduction(mission)
  h2 Hello world!
  p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

mixin mission_succeed(mission)
  h2 Congratulations!
  p You win buddy!

mixin mission_failed(mission)
  h2 Oh my gosh dude, you did something realy bad
  p You should try again
```

I was going to include that template in its parent but Jade disallows usage of expressions in the include's path. That why I try to interpret the jade code directly in the parent jade template but I didn't find how. I even tried to include it with the [`partial` function](https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials) but I can use that module without disable the default views inheritance strategy in Express.

**So where I'm wrong ? What is the best strategy for that king of architecture ?**

Cheers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finaly found a good strategy :

```
case mission.state
    when "game"
      block mission_introduction   
        h2 Hello world!
        p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

    when "succeed"
      block mission_succeed  
        h2 Congratulations!
        p You win buddy!              

    when "failed"
      block mission_failed                                    
        h2 Oh my gosh dude, you did something realy bad
        p You should try again
```

Cheers !